# generating Heteroskedasticity- & autocorrelation-consistent (HAC) standard errors for mixed effects (LMER) models

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, robust-standard-error

Is there a package/code for generating robust Heteroskedasticity- and autocorrelation-consistent (HAC) standard errors for mixed-effects models (specifically lmer models) in R?

I am aware of vcovHA,  but it only seems to work for lms.